# navigationBar setBackgroundImage not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set the background image of my navigation bar using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];

[self createInterface];


}

- (void) createInterface {
[viewController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

However, the app loads with no changes to the navigation bar's appearance. How can I fix this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {

          UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


            return YES;
        }
```

Comment: it will set background image for NavigationBar in all ViewControllers

Comment: For anyone else, this code is put in your AppDelegate. Thanks adnan! :)

Comment: There's your tick :P Thanks again!